# How to extend the sidebar to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I'm having some trouble with my sidebar on http://www.csgodrift.com/

Essentially, I want the .divchatfooter where users can enter in chat messages to be fixed to the bottom of the screen, and when users zoom out for it to remain fixed but have the .divchat height stretch instead.

Also, when users type in chat messages, rather than having the chat area height stay fixed it expands instead of having the messages scroll within that area.

I think it's easiest to test this if you login (if you have Steam) and Inspect Element but I've included the code in the jsfiddle if you'd prefer. https://jsfiddle.net/hwxsvqa5/ `jsfiddle`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may work The height should increase any time data is put in the chat. but you may need to set a `max-height` limit.

```
#divchatfooter {
  background-color: #1A1C26;
  padding-bottom: 5px;

  /*ADD THIS CODE*/
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
}
```

This should fix the width problem. There was padding on the right of the main element. So `width:inherit;` took the width of the main element + the padding. If you change this code it will make all width the same in the sidebar, however, it will make your sidebar longer by a few pixels.

Change it from `.mainsidebar { padding-left: 0px; }`

To the following

```
.mainsidebar {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This does solve the issue of having it fixed to the bottom, but now the problem is that the width of the chatfooter then isn't the same as the rest of the sidebar, and max-width doesn't work because it changes based on zoom level.

Comment: I updated my answer to include fixing the width problem.

Comment: Worked beautifully, thank you! Would you also happen to know how I can make the chatarea a fixed height that touches the chat input, and have the messages scroll? I tried to make it a textarea and even a text input but I can't get it to work like I want it to, just as a scrollable, fixed chat area.

Comment: I think that's an issue that would make a great question. Why don't you ask another question to related to that issue? To answer it here wouldn't be wise as others may not benefit.